# Partial Wave Analysis and Born Approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

im currently studying about scattering and there is something that is troubling me. The book im reading has been making a distinction between the Born approximation and partial wave analysis. For some potentials they are using partial waves and for some the Born approximation, specifically partial waves are used for potentials that have bounds (Hard sphere for example) and the Born approximation for smooth potentials (Yukawa Potential for example). My question is: aren't these methods suppose to be the same? Is it possible to use partial wave analysis for the Yukawa potenital for instance? How would you impose boundary conditions in a smooth potential?

Comment: Can I know what books you are referring to?

Comment: Quantum Mechanics: Concepts and Applications by Nouredine Zettili